# Vulkan Equivalent of gl_point and gl_linestrip

Tags: vulkan, point-clouds, polyline

I need to draw point clouds in Vulkan with points being 4 pixels wide.  I also need to draw polylines of varying thickness.  I have not seen any such demos in the Vulkan tutorial suite.  Could someone provide me with the right build commands for point clouds of varying size and polylines of varying thickness?

Answer (score 5):

Well, points are `VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINT_LIST` and line strip is `VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINE_STRIP` from `VkPrimitiveTopology`.

Special sizes need to be supported by GPU/driver. I.e. it can be done the easy way only if `largePoints` resp. `wideLines` from [`VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures) are supported. Then they are subject to further restrictions from [`VkPhysicalDeviceLimits`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPhysicalDeviceLimits).

Then you can change the point size by writing `gl_PointSize` (if you use `GLSL`) in a non-fragment shader.

Line size is changed at pipeline creation (`vkCreateGraphicsPipelines`) in `VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo` with `lineWidth`. Or you can make it a dynamic state (`VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo` with `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_LINE_WIDTH`), in which case you can change the size later at command buffer recording time with `vkCmdSetLineWidth`.

It should be a relatively easy modification of your typical [hello triangle](https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle) app with changing the above (and the vertex data of course).

Answer (score 0):

```
VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer{};
rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
rasterizer.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
rasterizer.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
rasterizer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE;
rasterizer.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;
```